# Why does the base class pointer point to the pure virtual method in the base class instead of the overidden method in the derived class?

Tags: c++, inheritance, gcc, run-time-polymorphism

```
#include <iostream>

class A
{
    public:
        virtual ~A() = default;
        virtual void foo(void) = 0;
};

class B : public A
{
    private:
        int x;

    public:
        B(int a) : x(a) {}
        void foo(void) { std::cout << "B: " << x << "\n"; }
};

class Foo
{
    private:
        A* a_ptr;

    public:
        Foo (B& x) { a_ptr = &x; }
        A* get_ptr(void) { return a_ptr; }
        void dummy(void) { std::cout << "Foo: "; std::cout << a_ptr << "\t "<< typeid(*a_ptr).name() << "\n"; a_ptr->foo(); std::cout << "\n"; }
};

int main(void)
{
        B b(10);
        Foo f(b);

        f.dummy();
        return 0;
}
```

If the constructor of `Foo` takes a reference to an object of `B`, then this program executes the way I expect it to, i.e. `a_ptr->foo()` calls `B::foo()`.

However, if the constructor is changed to accept the parameter by value, then `a_ptr->foo()` resolves to `A::foo()`, and results in a `pure virtual method called exception`

Sample output (Passed by reference:):

```
Foo: 0x7fffe90a24e0      1B
B: 10
```

Sample output (Passed by value):

```
Foo: 0x7fffc6bbab20      1A
pure virtual method called
terminate called without an active exception
Aborted (core dumped)
```

I've a vague hunch as to why this might be happening, and I'm looking for some literature or reference which might prove or disprove my hypothesis: When passed by reference, the base class pointer `a_ptr` points to an entity whose lifetime exceeds past the call to `a_ptr->foo()`.

However, when passed by value, `a_ptr` points to a temporary which is lost when the constructor exits.

I suppose this has something to do with the `VTABLE` of `A`, but I can't quite put my finger on it.

Comment: [Object slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-object-slicing)?

Comment: I might have close this wrong.  Did you change `Foo (B& x) { a_ptr = &x; }` to `Foo (B x) { a_ptr = &x; }`?

Comment: I don't think this is object slicing, its a pointer to a temporary

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. So far you’ve only posted code which doesn’t exhibit the problem you’re describing.

Comment: Show the code that doesn’t work, not the code that works.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Passing a `B` to a function that takes a `B` by value slices it?

Comment: @NathanOliver Whoops, nevermind that part, I though it was passing the `B` object as an `A`.  So yes, no slicing.

Comment: @All: Thank you for your inputs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, your suspicion is correct.

When the `B` object is passed *by value* into the `Foo` constructor, it becomes a local variable of the constructor. The constructor is saving a pointer to that local object, which goes out of scope when the constructor exits.

So, the call to `a_ptr->foo()` in `Foo::dummy()` is actually *undefined behavior* since `a_ptr` doesn't even point at a valid object to begin with.  But, it doesn't really crash since `A::foo()` doesn't use its `this` pointer for anything.  It just points to a compiler-defined function that throws the `pure virtual method called` error, which you don't catch, so your program terminates.

Answer (score 2):

You assigned temporary object B by reference to a_ptr which is of type A*. On constructor exit this temporary object has beed destroyed. As VTABLE has been destroyed too, called A::foo, which is pure virtual. So you got it.